# Right eigenvector λ and left eigenvector are orthogonal.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let x be a (right) eigenvector of A corresponding to an eigenvalue λ and let y be a left eigenvector of A corresponding to a different eigenvalue µ, where λ $\neq$ µ.   Show that x∗y = 0.  Hint : Ax = λx and y'A = µy'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Step 1)  $Ax=λx$
- Step 2) $y'Ax=λy'x$
- Step 3) $y'Ax-λy'x=0$
- Step 4) $(y'A-λy')x=0$
- Step 5) $(\mu y'-λy')x=0$
- Step 6) $(\mu-λ)y'x=0$
- How:
  $\mu \neq λ \implies \mu-λ \neq 0$
- This way:
  $y'x=0$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Calculate $y'Ax$ two different ways, and relate the answer to $y'x$.