# Show linear combination of complex vector given right and left eigenvectors of a matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

> Let $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ have distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with corresponding right eigenvectors $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and left eigenvectors $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, respectively. Let $v\in\mathbb C^n$ be an arbitrary vector. Show that $v$ can be expressed (uniquely) as a linear combination
> $$v=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i^Hv}{y_i^Hx_i}x_i$$
> of the right eigenvectos. Find the appropriate expression for $v$ as a linear combination of the left eigenvectors as well.

So far what I have is that
$$Ax_i = \lambda_ix_i \quad\text{ and } \quad y_i^HA=\lambda_iy_i^H$$

But I don't know where to proceed futher from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, it can be diagonalized as $A=X\Lambda X^{-1}$ where $x_i$ are the columns of $X$, and where $\lambda_i$ are the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. Similarly $A^H = Y\Lambda^H Y^{-1}$. Thus, $X\Lambda X^{-1} = (Y^H)^{-1} \Lambda Y^H$ which can be rearranged to
$$X^{-1} = \Lambda^{-1} X^{-1} (Y^H)^{-1} \Lambda Y^H = \Lambda^{-1} (Y^H X)^{-1} \Lambda Y^H.$$

Note that $Y^H X$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $y_i^H x_i$. (For why it is diagonal, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540412/right-eigenvector-%CE%BB-and-left-eigenvector-are-orthogonal).)

To conclude, use the above expression to show that the entries of the vector $X^{-1} v$ are $\frac{y_i^H v}{y_i^H x_i}$. Do you see why this implies the result in your question?

Comment: As per your question "Do you see... ?" I think I do. Take $X^{-1}v = \frac{y_i^Hv}{y_i^Hx_i}$, then left multiply by $X$ and get $v = X\frac{y_i^Hv}{y_i^Hx_i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i^Hv}{y_i^Hx_i}x_i$

Comment: so far I have that $$\Lambda^{-1}= \left[\begin{matrix}\frac 1{\lambda_1} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\0& \cdots &\frac1{\lambda_n} \end{matrix}\right], K=(Y^HX)^{-1}\Lambda^HY^H = \left[\begin{matrix} \frac{y_1^H\overline \lambda_1}{y_1^Hx_1} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots &\frac{y_n^H\overline \lambda_n}{y_n^Hx_n} \end{matrix}\right]$$ and then $$\Lambda^{-1}K = \left[\begin{matrix} \frac{y_1^H\overline \lambda_1}{\lambda_1y_1^Hx_1}& \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots &\frac{y_n^H\overline \lambda_n}{\lambda_ny_n^Hx_n}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Does $\frac{\overline \lambda_1}{\lambda_1} = 1?$ I assume so, but why?

Comment: @Seong I originally wrote $A^H = Y\Lambda Y^{-1}$, but based on your definition $y_i^H A = \lambda_i y^H$, I think it should be $A^H = Y\Lambda^H Y^{-1}$ instead (I've now edited my post). With this change, it should now work out.

Comment: Yes that is it!

Comment: I seem to have forgotten to handle the case where one of the eigenvalues is zero. I think it's possible for this proof to be modified to handle that case, but I am not certain.